# How to get scroll position of component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How could I get scroll position of a ReactJS component (-which is scrollable)? I suppose I have to add a scroll event listener to my component but I'm stuck there as I don't know how to add it to component - only to window. And also by which prop can I access the scroll position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scroller can be accessed via the ref. You will want to make sure the css is set to `overflow: scroll` or `overflow: auto` to ensure you actually get a scrollable content.

```js
class MyScroller extends React.Component {
  scroller = null
  
  componentDidMount = () => {
    if (this.scroller) {
      this.scroller.addEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this), false)
    }
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount = () => {
    if (this.scroller) {
      this.scroller.removeEventListener('scroll', this.handleScroll.bind(this), false)
    }
  }
  
  handleScroll = () => {
    if (this.scroller == null) return
    const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = this.scroller
    const scroll = scrollHeight - scrollTop - clientHeight

    if (scroll > 0) {
      // We are not at the bottom of the scroll content
    }
    else if (scroll == 0){
      // We are at the bottom
    }
  }

  render = () => (
    <div ref={rf => this.scroller = rf} className={styles.myScrollingContainer}>
      <MyScrollingStuff />
    </div>
  )

}
```

Comment: I'm using react hooks, so I suppose I need to use my ref as `useRef`? Well I tried that and it gives me error, saying that I can't add eventListener to the ref.

Comment: https://dev.to/n8tb1t/tracking-scroll-position-with-react-hooks-3bbj Here is an example using react hooks.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest option **without Reference**:

```
class MyScroller extends React.Component {

  handleScroll = (event) => {
    const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = event.target;
    const scroll = scrollHeight - scrollTop - clientHeight

    if (scroll > 0) {
      // We are not at the bottom of the scroll content
    }
    else if (scroll == 0){
      // We are at the bottom
    }
  }

  render = () => (
    <div onScroll={this.handleScroll} className={styles.myScrollingContainer}>
      <MyScrollingStuff />
    </div>
  )

}
```

This approach is cleaner and much more efficient since script don't need to operate on real DOM.

Comment: I get -1 for the value of the scroll all the time whats the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you have to use onScroll function on your div, span, whatever

```
<TableContainer className={classes.container} onScroll={handleScroll}>
```

handleScroll is this function, if scroll position is down then request to your db

```
const handleScroll = async event => {
    const { scrollHeight, scrollTop, clientHeight } = event.target
    const scrollPosition = scrollHeight - scrollTop - clientHeight
    if (scrollPosition <= 0) {
      onRequest()
    }
  }
```

approch 2, you can use useRef to your component

```
class ScrollAwareDiv extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.myRef = React.createRef()
    this.state = {scrollTop: 0}
  }
  
  onScroll = () => {
    const scrollY = window.scrollY //Don't get confused by what's scrolling - It's not the window
    const scrollTop = this.myRef.current.scrollTop
    console.log(`onScroll, window.scrollY: ${scrollY} myRef.scrollTop: ${scrollTop}`)
    this.setState({
      scrollTop: scrollTop
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {
      scrollTop
    } = this.state
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.myRef}
        onScroll={this.onScroll}
         >
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
        <p>This demonstrates how to get the scrollTop position within a scrollable react component.</p>
        <p>ScrollTop is {scrollTop}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <ScrollAwareDiv />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```